# Код не проходит на страницу пользователя Instagram и не подписывается на него

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, бот, instagram

Есть код на основе Python, который заходит в определенную группу в Instagram, открывает всех ее подписчиков, а затем заходит на страницу каждого из них и подписывается на него. Однако при сборе списка подписчиков группы питон собирает пустой список. Очевидно, проблема в куске с определением HDMI-маркеров. Помогите подобрать правильную последовательность. Сам код написан на основе библиотеки selenium.
Кусок кода, который должен зайти на страницу пользователя и подписаться на него:

```
# подписываемся на каждого из подписчиков
while True:
    number_user = 1
    
    try:
        count_followers_today = 0

        while count_followers_today < 40:
            try:
                # Находим первого подписчика в группе и кликаем на него
                first_follower = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, rf'//div[@class="PZuss"]/li[{number_user}]/div/div[{number_user}]/div/a')
                first_follower.click()

                # Ожидаем, пока страница с подписчиком загрузится полностью
                time.sleep(10)

                # Нажимаем кнопку "Подписаться" на странице подписчика
                subscribe_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Подписаться"]')
                subscribe_button.click()
                
                number_user += 1
                count_followers_today += 1

                time.sleep(10)

            except:
                pass
        
    except:
        break
```

Ошибка возникает при выполнении данных строк:

```
first_follower = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, rf'//div[@class="PZuss"]/li[{number_user}]/div/div[{number_user}]/div/a')
                    first_follower.click()
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться что тут не так.
Ошибка ниже:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class="PZuss"]/li[1]/div/div[1]/div/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.134)
```

Comment: ошибку-то приведите, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, спасибо за комментарий,  добавил в вопрос ошибку. Продублирую и сюда:

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class="PZuss"]/li[1]/div/div[1]/div/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.134)

Comment: @ДмитрийЛевицкий селениум не находит такого элемента, поэтому и выдаёт ошибку. Используйте расширение для браузера (какой-нибудь условный xpathfinder) для поиска правильного пути. А возможно, что такой путь есть, но после того, как страница полностью загрузится.